# Addon product support in VirtoCOmmerce 2 . How to implement it?

Tags: e-commerce, product, virtocommerce

I have a use case where i need to do the following :

1. I have a shop selling tshirts
2. I want to be able to give the customer an optional feature of printing a line of text on the tshirt with an additional charge.
3. In the product detail page the base price (say $10.0) is displayed against the product and a checkbox with the line printing options is displayed with an additional charge of $2
4. If the user adds only the tshirt to the cart without checking the line print option checkbox then cart total is $10.00 . If the product is added with the line print option checked then the cart total is $12.00
5. User should be able to add X no of tshirts with no print option and Y number of tshirts with print option .

Is the above possible in VC2 Community edition ?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment such functionality is not presented in VC2 out-of-the-box.

Seems you describe so called "bundle" product. It allows to organize multiple items in the storefront cart into one product, with ability to manipulate quantities of inner items.

Something similar could be achieved by having t-shirt product, and having its variations - with or without printed text. You could specify different prices for them, and have different quantities in one order.

Also you could have 2 different products - t-shirt and print (or t-shirt with print). That way using promotions functionality you'd have an ability to tune some discounts/rewards for having both in one order.